# VueJs how to set prop type to any?

Tags: vue.js

I have props with defined types  but I want the last one of them to accept any kind of value

```
props: {
        Size: String,
        Label: String,
        Name: String,
        value: Any
    }
```

Hpw can I achieve this?

Comment: Set it to `null` to match any type.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

From [VueJS docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation):

> `null` and `undefined` values will pass any type validation

Or you can use array and place in it all required types:

```
propB: [String, Number]
```

Comment: `null` and `undefined` will pass any type validation - just make sure `required` is **not** set to `true`. [Found it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125043/vuejs-using-prop-type-validation-with-null-and-undefined-values)

Answer (score 4):

To support props type `any` when you have props with defined types:

```js
props: {
    custom1: null, // set as `null`
    custom2: undefined,  // or `undefined`
       
    // if you need to add extra rules, simply don't set the `type` prop
    custom3: {
        required: true,
        //... rest of your props
    }
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/xa91zoyq/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm doing to pass lint validation.
You could of corse do real validation here.
There are many handy methods that [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isObject) provides for checking types

```
value: {
  required: true,
  validator: v => true
},
```

Comment: Now that i think about it it should not allow undefined ‍♂️ 
so i would do something like this... `validator: v => !_.isUndefined(v)`