# VueJS Using Prop Type Validation With NULL and 'undefined' Values?

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, types, vuejs2

Even though [VueJS 2 official documentation about prop validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation) is stating (as a code example's comment line):

> // Basic type check (`null` and `undefined` values will pass any type
> validation)

**I'm getting the following error with [this code reproduction](https://vuep.run/6ecbe302) — why is that?**

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String, Number, Boolean, got Null
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ title }}:</h1>
    <MyInput :value="null" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
Vue.component('MyInput', Vue.extend({
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String, Number, Boolean],
      required: true,
    },
  },
  template: `
    <select v-model="value">
      <option value="null">
        null value
      </option>
      <option value="">
        Empty value
      </option>
    </select>`,
}));

export default {
  data: () => ({
    title: 'VueJS Using Prop Type Validation With NULL and `undefined` Values?'
  }),
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> // Basic type check (`null` and `undefined` values will pass any type validation)

This applies only when `required: true` is NOT set. In your code,  you are saying that the prop is required and so Vuejs is showing the warning

Related discussion: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/shouldnt-null-be-accepted-as-prop-value-with-any-type/63887

Comment: Note: If you *want* to also allow `null`, the use a validator: `validator: prop => typeof prop === 'string' || prop === null`

Comment: in vue3, ive declared it this way ```value: {
    type: String as PropType<string | null>,
    default: null,
    required: false,
  }
```

Comment: @JamesTan This leads to another error: "Expected String with value "null", got Null"

Comment: @mediafreakch is that a vue / ts error?

Comment: @JamesTan Yes, but I figured it's coming from a component deeper down the tree that still had a `required: true` prop type definition. So if passing down props, make sure all components have the correct prop type definition

Answer (score 12):

It's because of `required: true`

From [API docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props) (more detail)

> required: Boolean
> Defines if the prop is required. In a non-production environment, a console warning will be thrown if this value is truthy and the prop is not passed.

Answer (score 10):

[PropType](https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html) with the **Vue3**

```
<script lang="ts">

import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
  ...
  },
  name: 'Component',

  props: {
    value: { 
      type: null as unknown as PropType<string | null>,
      default: null, required: false
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: this also works if you use an object, hence type can be `type: null as unknown as PropType<string | YourType | null>` nice

Comment: related discussion on vue 3 GitHub issues: [vue: define required nullable props #3948](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/3948)

Answer (score 2):

As Cato mentioned using a `validator` can help solve this issue.

You will need to provide a `default` and make sure `required` is not set or is `false`.

```js
<script>
Vue.component('MyInput', Vue.extend({
    props: {
        value: {
            type: [String, Number, Boolean],
            default: null,
            validator: (p) => {
                return ['string', 'number', 'boolean'].indexOf(typeof p) !== -1 || p === null;
            },
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

This may look like it will work the same as this...

```js
<script>
Vue.component('MyInput', Vue.extend({
    props: {
        value: {
            type: [String, Number, Boolean],
            required: false,
            default: null,
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

However, in the second example you can pass `undefined`. In the first you can pass the listed types plus `null`.