# vue 3 typescript props require custom type but allow null

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component that must receive a `selectedDistrict` prop of type `SelectedDistrict`.
Note that a valid value is `null`. This means that no district was selected. However `undefined` is not valid.

My goal is to be notified at runtime when the parent component does not pass `:selectedDistrict`.

```
export type DistrictData = null | {
  id: string
  name: string
}

const Child = defineComponent({
  props: {
    selectedDistrict: {
      type: Object as PropType<DistrictData>,
      required: true,
    }
  }
})
```

**Parent**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Child :selectedDistrict="selectedDistrict" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
// ..
data: () => ({
  selectedDistrict: null as DistrictData,
})
```

The above situation I will get a warning in the console because `required: true` and the value of selectedDistrict is null.

If I remove `required: true` I will get *no* warning when I forget to pass `:selectedDistrict` on `<Child />`. (it will be undefined)

I cannot use a **custom validator** as far as I know, because I can't `typeof DistrictData` (type used as value error).

How can I make it so that I:

- get an error when `selectedDistrict` is undefined
- get no error when `selectedDistrict` is null

Or do I have to take a completely different approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125043/vuejs-using-prop-type-validation-with-null-and-undefined-values

Comment: I found that one too. The difference with my question is that I want to check a custom type. So I can't use a validator with `typeof`

Comment: For your use case, a validator wouldn't work because it's only called when a value is given; and even in that case, you could check for the required fields of the type (no need for `typeof`). I don't see a solution that would satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. To fix this I think I'll split it up: use a primitive to check for changes and then a getter to pull the data from the parent.