# How to use `null` to define an empty ref in Vue 3 & TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 and TypeScript with the script setup tag (`<script setup lang="ts">`.

And I often have a ref inside a composable that looks like this:

```
const composableMessage = ref<string | null>(null);
```

It's a string or a number or something with an inital "empty" value. And I am intentionally using `null` instead of `undefined` to define "empty" because I prefer it.

Then I have a child component with a prop that looks like this:

```
defineProps({
  messageProp: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: '',
  },
});
```

And when using it in a parent component like this:

```
import myComposable from '/src/composables/myComposable';
const { composableMessage } = myComposable();
<my-component :messageProp="composableMessage" />
```

I get this TypeScript error on `:messageProp`:

```
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

If I use `const composableMessage = ref<string | undefined>(undefined);` the TypeScript error goes away, but I would much rather keep it as `null`.

Why am I forced into using `undefined` for empty refs?

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the other way around, your `messageProp` accepts only `string` or `undefined` due to the `required: false`, but you try to send it `string` or `null`.

The link I sent as comment [VueJS Using Prop Type Validation With NULL and 'undefined' Values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125043/vuejs-using-prop-type-validation-with-null-and-undefined-values) does not seem to work with Vue3 and Volar/Typescript.

So to accept null you should change the prop type of `messageProp` as follows

```
defineProps({
  messageProp: {
    type: String as PropType<string|null>,
    required: false,
    default: '',
  },
});
```

(note: I do not expect the default value ('') to be set for `null`, only `undefined`, so you'd probably need to handle the null value yourself)

(note2: you do not need to write `ref<string | undefined>(undefined)` you'd get the same `Ref<string|undefined>` object with `ref<string>()`)

Comment: Would it make more sense to abandon the use of `null` in favor of `undefined`? I guess that would save me having to always use `PropType<>`. How do you personally define empty refs?

Comment: @TinyTiger during the last few years with Vue it's been very rare to ever use `null`, mostly due to external APIs declaring properties in a JSON but with null values. I prefer `undefined`, ie not sending the property (using optional properties in Typescript). But it all boils down to what "empty" is for you. For an empty string I use '', but if it is not set at all I use `undefined`.

Comment: I think you are right, and I have shifted towards `undefined` because it works better with optional properties in Typescript and Vue Props.